# import cv2 error on django ImportError: libGL.so.1

Tags: python, django, docker, opencv

i'm working on a django project and i need to use the webcam. i've tried to install opencv-python with pip but python give me back the error `ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.
i've tried to install libGL.so.1 inside Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libgl1 -y
```

but I haven't solved my problem.

Comment: you need to take the [tour] and then read [ask]. -- [search for your error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ImportError%3A+libGL.so.1%3A+cannot+open+shared+object+file%3A+No+such+file+or+directory)

Comment: Can you show your `Dockerfile`? What is your base image?

Comment: install opencv-python-headless instead (which does not depend on gui related libs like gl)

Comment: "and i need to use the webcam. " -- which webcam, exactly ? think of it, please. do you expect a webcam plugged into a *webserver* ? (wont happen) do you expect your local cam connect to a webserver by magic ? (wont happen, either)

Answer (score 0):

Installing dev file of opencv might solve this problem.

```
apt-get install -y libopencv-dev
```

Comment: did you try it? does it solve the problem for sure or is this just a suggestion?

Comment: It solved the problem from my end.